# Getting the min, max, and ave of the five numbers inputted

Tags: c, arrays, max, min, minmax

I'm trying to work on a program in C that gets 5 input numbers and then **store these in an array.** After getting the the 5 numbers, **I must be getting the min, max and the average of the MINIMUN AND MAXIMUM numbers inputted and not all of the five.** So here's the code that I made. When I get the maximum number, it seems to be working fine. But when it come's to the min, it's still same as the maximum and so I'll be getting a different average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
int num[5];
int counter, min, max=0;
float average, total;
min=num;

for(counter=1; counter<=5; counter++)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num[5]);

    if(num[5]>max)
    {
        max = num[5];
    }

    if (num[5]<min)
    {
        min = num[5];
    }
}

total = min + max;
average = total/2;

printf("The maximum number is: %d\n", max);
printf("The minimum number is: %d\n", min); 
printf("The average is: %d", average);


getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: average=sum of all five numbers/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a learning exercise, I wouldn't correct your code, but point out what needs to be fixed:

- Arrays in C are indexed from zero, not from one, so the counter should go from 0 to 4, inclusive
- `min` is an `int`, while `num` is an array, so the assignment `min=num` is invalid
- `scanf` should put the data into `&num[count]`, not `&num[5]`
- In the way that you coded your loop you do not need an array at all: you need the last number entered.
- `total` cannot be computed as `min+max`; you need to keep a running total, updating it on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed some from your suggestions. But what do you mean by inclusive min is an int, while num is an array, so the assignment min=num is invalid? And total cannot be computed as min+max? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @WreckitJennica, consider: 1 1 1 1 5.  The data is weighted towards 1, NOT evenly dispersed.

Comment: @WreckitJennica `num` is an array of integers. You need to say what `int` you want to take from it by specifying an index, i.e. `min = num[0]`, `min = num[2]`, etc. As far as `min+max` goes, consider `1,2,3,4,100` with the average of `110/5=22`. `min+max`, on the other hand, is `101`, so the average will be wrong.